# Nothing will connect to mysql on localhost

Tags: mysql, localhost, database-connection

I've tried just about everything I can find online. I'm going to try to make a complete list of all of the things that I have tried in no particular order (as it's been about two weeks of hunting for solutions). Where it all starts is my formerly functioning local dev setup was working fine aside from some SQL settings that were interfering with my already established codebase. I found resources online that detailed editing my.cnf file; which I did. From that point forward, nothing will connect to mysql.

**1. Uninstall and remove mysql files via terminal**

**2. Reinstalled mysql and attempted to connect via terminal, didn't work**
Running via terminal: `mysql -u root`
Resulting socket error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

**3. Connected to services via DBngin**
All services start up and seem to run fine; (Homebrew svcs: php, mysql, httpd). All show a green light and appear to be functioning.

**4. Attempt to connect to mySQL via TablePlus**
These settings worked before I messed with my.cnf file as described initially (no password):
`Host: 127.0.0.1`
`Port: 3306`
`User: root`

Resulting error: `Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)`

**5. Installed MySQL Workbench / Server, won't connect**
Resulting error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

**6. Any attempt to load localhost:3306 in Chrome/Safari/Firefox all result in the following**
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

**7. See if mySQL is running**

Run in terminal: `ps aux |grep mysql`

Results in: `natashya         74640   0.0  0.0 34132100    908 s002  S+    1:40pm   0:00.00 grep mysql`

Try to kill via: `kill 74640`

Results in: `kill: kill 74640 failed: no such process`

Run: `brew services restart mysql`

Results in: `` ==> Successfully stopped `mysql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql) ==> Successfully started `mysql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql) ``

**Contents of my.cnf**

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
# Only allow connections from localhost

[mysqld]

bind-address = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
port = 3306
mysqlx-port = 33060
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 
datadir = /usr/local/mysql
tmpdir = /tmp
mysqlx=OFF

[client]

port = 3306
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Thank you so much to Bill Karwin for help. I am however still unable to resolve the site I'm attempting to access (localhost:9000) and get this error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

Comment: Your `ps` showed that only the command `grep mysql` was running. The actual MySQL Server process is not running. Naturally process 74640 is not running either a moment later, because your `grep mysql` command finished.  I'd check the MySQL error log (probably under the data dir) for clues about why it isn't staying running after homebrew starts it. It might be crashing or exiting because of file permisisons.

Comment: These two errors seem to be repeated over and over again:
```2022-11-19T19:04:03.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/NatashywMacBook.lan.err'.
2022-11-19T19:04:03.6NZ mysqld_safe Directory '/var/lib/mysql' for UNIX socket file don't exists.```

Comment: What do you see if you run `ls /var/lib/mysql`? Does that directory exist?

Comment: Very strange... I get this `ls: /var/lib/mysql: No such file or directory`

Comment: Indeed, that is consistent with the error log message "file don't exists." You must either create that directory, or else change your my.cnf to specify a different directory (that does exist) for the socket file.

Comment: I ran `mkdir /var/lib/mysql` and it kicked back so I ran `sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql` which prompted my password, and returned back seemingly fine. I'm able to access folder now via `cd /var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: Make sure the directory has permissions such that the MySQL Server process can create the socket file, then try starting the service as you did before. Then look in the error log as it start ups. It should eventually say "Ready for connections."

Comment: Added my user with read & write permissions on that folder. Strangely, it kicked back saying mysql was still running. ```natashya@NatashywMacBook ~ % brew services start mysql
Service `mysql` already started, use `brew services restart mysql` to restart.
natashya@NatashywMacBook ~ % brew services restart mysql
Stopping `mysql`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mysql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql)
==> Successfully started `mysql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql)```

I do see a new file in /var/lib/mysql now: mysql.sock.lock

Comment: Maybe the service was continually trying to start, and once you created the directory it finally succeeded.

Comment: I started the PHP server as well `php -S localhost:3306` and I still get this error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

Comment: But MySQL Server is running? You can use the MySQL client to connect?

Comment: Amazing -- the mysql client connects, TablePlus. Thank you!

Comment: ```natashya         13984   0.0  0.0 34141316    948 s000  S+    2:31pm   0:00.00 grep mysql
natashya         13473   0.0  0.4 34868928  69204   ??  S     2:20pm   0:01.85 /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/opt/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=NatashywMacBook.lan.err --pid-file=NatashywMacBook.lan.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
natashya         13293   0.0  0.0 34136616   1264   ??  S     2:20pm   0:00.03 /bin/sh /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql```

Comment: I still can't connect in browser via `http://localhost:3306/`
Result in browser: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

Comment: Yeah, the browser is not the right client for MySQL. The browser uses the http protocol, and MySQL has its own protocol. It sounds like you are a beginner. You need to do some more studying to understand how web applications work. It's too much to cover in a Stack Overflow answer. There are books on this subject.

Comment: Yeah -- I did outline that I'm a beginner; however, I'm not attempting to view mysql via browser. I am attempting to view my php application locally while being connected to a mysql db.

Comment: Yes, you would use the browser to send an http request to your PHP app. The PHP app connects to MySQL, gets some data, formats it in HTML, and returns an http response to the browser. Browsers cannot connect directly to MySQL.

Comment: I'm aware of this. :) The above error message was outlined in my initial post that I have been unable to connect to mysql (which we've resolved) and that I am also unable to resolve the site in localhost. That's what I'm looking to resolve. I will post a separate question if that's the best way to handle.

Comment: 3306 is the port used by MySQL Server. You can't have an http on that port on the same computer. Only one service can listen on a given port on the same network interface. So you shouldn't start your PHP service with `php -S localhost:3306` because that port is already in use. Choose another port.

Comment: Ah, I figured -- was just testing things. I had tried on :9000 as that's what I normally use, and I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux of the comment thread above:

- Check the MySQL Server error log for clues.
- The log indicated the directory for the socket files, /var/lib/mysql, did not exist.
- Once the directory was created with the right permissions, the MySQL Server process created the socket file.

Also:

- `ps aux | grep mysql` matches the process running `grep mysql` because the word 'mysql' appears in that command.